# Directive isn't updated when new data comes in if called from another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have started to use directives with ui-router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('book', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:book',
    template: '<book-tabs />'
  })
  .state('book.about', {
    url: '',
    template: '<book-about />'
  })
  .state('book.stats', {
    url: '/statistics',
    template: '<book-stats />'
  });
```

Here is one of the directives:

```
  export default function(app) {
    app.directive('bookStats', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'statsTab',
        templateUrl: 'book-stats.tpl.html',
        controller: 'BookStatsCtrl'
      };
    });
  };
```

Inside of `book-stats` directive I want to call `stats-list` directive and pass `book` object, that is empty at first, but has data after HTTP request is fulfilled:

```
var vm = this;
vm.book = {};
Book.get.single({bookId: id}).then(function(res) {
    vm.book= res; // there is data
    return res;
});
```

In template:

```
<stats-list book="statsTab.book"></stats-list>
```

And here is `stats-list` directive:

```
export default function(app) {
  app.directive('statsList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        book: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'stats-list.tpl.html',
      controller: 'CircleRankListCtrl'
    };
  });
};
```

**When initialized, `stats-list` directive is called with a empty `book` object as a parameter, and when HTTP request is fulfilled and `book` object gets some data, but `stats-list` directive doesn't update.**

**When I tried to call `$scope.$apply` inside of a callback I got `$digest already in progress` error.**

I used Angular 1.4.7 but I also tried to changed it all to Angular 1.5 components.

Comment: Show `stats-list.tpl.html` template.

Comment: also directive shouldn't be using self closing tag, then should closed properly like `<book-tabs></book-tabs>`

Comment: you just forgot to use `bindToController : true`. Then it would have worked even with the simple `vm.book = {}` object. Your are using the dot syntax already .http://jsfiddle.net/5L62zuke/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miško Hevery gave a good talk about this problem [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1758s), and you can find the solution explained in other blog posts as well (like [this one](http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/#sthash.M5Yiy3vM.dpbs) by Courtney Robinson).

*Summary*: If you don't have a dot, you're doing it wrong.

**The Problem**: Your `book` key is assigned a new value when the promise is fulfilled...

```
Book.get.single({bookId: id}).then(function(res) {
  vm.book= res; // here
  return res;
});
```

so whatever value your original `book` parameter had in the child directive has just been overridden in (and is no longer bound to the) parent directive `book`.

**A Solution**: is to keep `book` tied to an object, and pass that object to the child directive.  That way, when the `book` key on that object changes, the reference to the containing object will remain bound to the object in the parent directive.

```
vm.statsObj.book = {};
Book.get.single({bookId: id}).then(function(res) {
  vm.statsObj.book= res; // there is data
  return res;
});

<stats-list stats-obj="statsTab.statsObj"></stats-list>

export default function(app) {
  app.directive('statsList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        statsObj: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'stats-list.tpl.html',
      controller: 'CircleRankListCtrl'
    };
  });
};
```

then in the `stats-list.tpl.html` template your reference to `book` will remain bound to the book in the parent directive

```
{{statsObj.book}}
```